# Hive: Select all rows with a range from the max of a column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

So I am trying to write a query in Hive that will then be automated. The idea is I have a table that shows Requests with a timestamp field called updated. So there are alot of rows with the date and time at which the Request was made. Regardless of when the query is run I want to get the Requests from the last 7 days.

I tried:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt       
FROM table
WHERE updated BETWEEN date_sub(SELECT MAX(updated) AS maxdate FROM table, 7) 
                      AND SELECT MAX(updated) AS maxdate FROM table 
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING cnt > 10
```

I have looked over this and  It seems like it should do what I am looking for, however I get:

```
ParseException line 4:79 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in function specification
```

Any help on this error or a suggested diffrent approach would be great.

Comment: THe last 7 days from now or from the last submited date?

Comment: The last seven days from the moment this query is executed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query, if the data type of column "updated" is datatime in all tables:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt       
FROM table
WHERE updated BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(updated)-7 AS maxdate FROM table)
AND (SELECT MAX(updated) AS maxdate FROM table)
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

Comment: There is only a single table in this query and updated is a TIMESTAMP. I have tried this part of the query independently : date_sub(SELECT MAX(updated) AS maxdate FROM table, 7) and it gives me the correct date